# Split string column into multiple columns in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table as below -

```
+------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|cus_id|cus_nm                           |pur_region     |purchase_dt  |pur_details                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0121  |Johnny                           |USA            |2023-01-12   |[{product_id=XA8096521JKAZ42F123, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_rolex_GZ, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|0137  |Kevin J Brown                    |USA            |2022-05-31   |[{product_id=XA14567JKR700135126, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_rolex_LA, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|0168  |Patrikson                        |UK             |2022-11-08   |[{product_id=XAHJYZK906423623571, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_gucci_09, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|0365  |Ryan Ray                         |USA            |2021-10-12   |[{product_id=XAOPLKR7520HJV00109, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_vancleef, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|2600  |Jay                              |AUS            |2022-11-11   |[{product_id=XA096534987GGHJLRAC, product_name=sports_eyewear, description=athlete sports sun glasses, check=sale_item, sale_price_gap=BOGO 20% off, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=report}]                                         |
+------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The schema of this table is -

```
root
 |-- cus_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cus_nm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pur_region: string (nullable = true)
 |-- purchase_dt: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pur_details: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to split the column `pur_details` and extract `check` and `sale_price_gap` as separate columns.
Note that the `pur_details` may or may not have `check` and `sale_price_gap`, so if it's not present in `pur_details` then the new column values should be null.

Sample expected output -

```
+------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|cus_id|cus_nm                           |pur_region     |purchase_dt  |check     |sale_price_gap       |pur_details                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0121  |Johnny                           |USA            |2023-01-12   |sale_item |upto 30% on_sale     |[{product_id=XA8096521JKAZ42F123, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_rolex_GZ, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|0137  |Kevin J Brown                    |USA            |2022-05-31   |sale_item |upto 30% on_sale     |[{product_id=XA14567JKR700135126, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_rolex_LA, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|0168  |Patrikson                        |UK             |2022-11-08   |sale_item |upto 30% on_sale     |[{product_id=XAHJYZK906423623571, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_gucci_09, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|0365  |Ryan Ray                         |USA            |2021-10-12   |sale_item |upto 30% on_sale     |[{product_id=XAOPLKR7520HJV00109, product_name=luxury_watch_collection_vancleef, description=mens watch round dail on sale, check=sale_item, tag=watch, sale_price_gap=upto 30% on_sale, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=entry}]      |
|2600  |Jay                              |AUS            |2022-11-11   |sale_item |BOGO 20% off         |[{product_id=XA096534987GGHJLRAC, product_name=sports_eyewear, description=athlete sports sun glasses, check=sale_item, sale_price_gap=BOGO 20% off, sale_vendor=mrporter.com, action=report}]                                         |
+------+---------------------------------+---------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Can someone please help me with the best and efficient way when I have millions of rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? try to take a look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object.html, your path should be something like `'$[0].check'` and `'$[0].sale_price_tag'`

Comment: That's not a JSON string. Fields are separated with a `=` sign. @SaarLevy

Comment: @meysam, you are correct, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few assumptions like there is no `,` on strings except those separate fields, I hope this code helps you to get an idea to achieve what you want:

```
df.withColumn("pur_details_split", split(col("pur_details"), ","))
    .withColumn("check", element_at(split(element_at(filter(col("pur_details_split"), x => trim(x).startsWith("check")), 1), "="), 2))
    .withColumn("sale_price_gap", element_at(split(element_at(filter(col("pur_details_split"), x => trim(x).startsWith("sale_price_gap")), 1), "="), 2))
    .select("check", "sale_price_gap")
    .show(false)

+---------+----------------+
|check    |sale_price_gap  |
+---------+----------------+
|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|sale_item|null            |
+---------+----------------+
```

Ps 1. I can't remember the python equivalencies of Spark API, but I'm pretty sure they are similar to Scala ones.

Ps 2. I removed `sale_price_gap` from the last record on the original dataframe to support the scenario of non-existent value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use regexp_extract, which reduces the code and might be faster.

```py
df.withColumn("check",F.regexp_extract("pur_details", "check=([^,}]*)(.*)" ,1))\
  .withColumn("sale_price_gap",F.regexp_extract("pur_details", "sale_price_gap=([^,}]*)(.*)" ,1))\
  .show()
```

You can test the regex here
[check regexp](https://regex101.com/r/unjHe2/1)

```
+--------------------+-------+---------+----------------+
|         pur_details|cust_id|    check|  sale_price_gap|
+--------------------+-------+---------+----------------+
|[{product_id=XA80...|   0121|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|[{product_id=XA14...|   0137|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|[{product_id=XAHJ...|   0168|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|[{product_id=XAOP...|   0365|sale_item|upto 30% on_sale|
|[{product_id=XA09...|   2600|sale_item|    BOGO 20% off|
+--------------------+-------+---------+----------------+
```